# creating stand-alone executable for windows from python code

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a python code which uses the pygkt, gtk, ctypes, os and some other modules. I used pyinstaller to create a stand-alone executive of the code. It worked fine on ubuntu. Now I wanted to create another stand-alone executive for windows platform.
     I used the tool  https://github.com/paulfurley/python-windows-packager for it and followed the steps. But I got the error: module gtk not found.
     How to fix the issue ?
     Are there any other tools to convert python code to stand-alone executable for windows os ? If yes, please provide the details ?
     Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd recommend using [pyinstaller](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/)

**Example:**

```
$ pip install pyinstaller
$ pyinstaller -F myscript.py
```

You should now have a `build/myscript/myscript.exe` executable.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But needed to install pywin32, and pygtk.msi file for it to work. And the executable is stored in sample/dist/myscript.exe

Comment: great man , py2exe gave me resource error but pyinstaller worked for me , thanks :)

Comment: Aged thread, still useful. Using 3.7, this syntax worked for me: "py pyinstaller.py --onefile --noconsole scriptName.py"

Answer (score 2):

If in Windows, Best way to do it is via Cygwin.
Ensure you have Python 3.5+ version not 3.6

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Go to the directory where the .py file is which needs to be packaged.

Then run

```
$ pyinstaller --onefile test.py
```

Simple to have a single file executable.